# DbConcurrencyException when removing an entity in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am learning ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 from the getting started tutorials on MSDN. I have limited experience with Entity Framework and have come across an issue.

I am using the ASP.NET 5 Web Application Template with Individual User Accounts authentication type. I have created a controller and view for performing crud operations on my model class. Other than this I have not modified the template code. I have added and applied an initial migration to the db.

I am able to add instances of my model class without any problems to the localdb but when removing an entry I get the following error

> Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext: Error: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes.
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithoutPropagation(Int32 commandIndex, DbDataReader reader)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.Consume(DbDataReader reader)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
>
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
>
> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' in EntityFramework.Core.dll

The relevant bits of code are as follows

```
public class DeveloperController : Controller
{
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public DeveloperController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;    
        }
...
// POST: Developer/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(ApplicationUser applicationUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Users.Add(applicationUser);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(applicationUser);
        }
...
// POST: Developer/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            ApplicationUser applicationUser = _context.Users.Single(m => m.Id == id);
            _context.Users.Remove(applicationUser);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
}
```

Stepping through the code while debugging seems to indicate that the applicationUser is being correctly retrieved and marked for deletion but as soon as `_context.SaveChanges()` is called there is an exception.

I've tried searching for solutions to the problem for the past few hours but have not had success so far. Any help as to why adding entities works but removing does not will be appreciated. I can add entities and they are definitely saved since stopping the debugger completely and relaunching, the entities are still there but cannot be deleted.

Thanks

Comment: It's probably an issue with the _context.  What is your code for the Delete action (i.e., the HttpGet)?

Comment: Can you make a delete in another entity besides User to see if it works? If it also doesn't work, then you really have a problem with your _context.

Comment: @jpgrassi Ok, it turns out that I am able to remove other entities. I created a test entity and am able to add and remove it without any issue. Does this indicate that ApplicationUser has foreign keys that I was earlier unaware of?

Comment: That would be my best guess.

Comment: @jpgrassi Thank you. How would I mark this as solved since technically there is no answer?

Comment: Did you happen to find that the foreign keys where the problem? If you did find what was the issue in your case, you can post what you did to solve as an answer. Just make sure to make it clear and well formatted.

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issues, whenever I create a new user I can't edit/delete that user.  But if i register a new user, then i can edit/delete that user.  I believe it has something to do with manually adding an entry into the table via db.add(model) vs the way var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);